# If $U ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $B ⊂ U$, then why is it that $B$ relatively open in $U$ if and only if $B$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

If $U ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $B ⊂ U$, then why is it that $B$ relatively open in $U$ if and only if $B$ is open?

I can prove it for closed sets. Does it follow directly from what's below that the same is true for open sets?
For example, I assume $A$ is a closed set. Since $A ⊂ E$ and $A$ is we have that $A = E ∩ A$.  So $A$ can be written as the intersection of finite number of closed sets with $E$. Therefore $A$ is relatively closed in $E$. Next assume that $A$ is relatively closed in E. Then, there must exist a closed set $S$ such that $A = E ∩ B$.  Because $E$ is closed here, $A$ is the intersection of two closed sets, so $A$ is a closed set as well since intersections of closed sets are closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is relatively open in $U$, then there exists an open set $V\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $B=U\cap V$ and so $B$ is open, sine $U\cap V$ is open.

If $B$ is open, then $B=B\cap U$ and so it is relatively open in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Change closed to open and you are basically done. But let's recap why things work out here. How is relatively open/closed even defined? The answer is simple:

Consider $(X, \tau)$ some topological space. Let $A\subset X$ be a subset. Then we can equip $A$ with the *pullback* (or also called *weakest*) topology induced by the inclusion $ \iota: A \to X$. Denote this topology by $\tau_{A}$. Observe $$\tau_{A}= \{\iota^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \tau\}=\{U \cap A \mid U \in \tau \}$$

So a set $V \subset A$ is open in $A$ (i.e. relatively) *if and only if* it can be written as the intersection of some $U$ open in $X$ and $A$.